# Getting an error when inserting a new record to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am using Rails 3.2.3 on Ubuntu and below is my schema file and model file code:

***schema.rb***

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120528062318) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true

end
```

***user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  valides :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

i tried to enter a new record to the database from the rails console with the command: User.create(name: 'Hilal Agil', email: 'hilaal@me.com', password: 'welcome', password_confirmation: 'welcome') and i am getting the error below:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `valides' for #<Class:0xaeba6cc>
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
        from /home/hilarl/workspace/twitster/app/models/user.rb:17:in `<class:User>'
        from /home/hilarl/workspace/twitster/app/models/user.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_consta
nt'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_miss
ing'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3p194 :003 >
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong here? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo.
This line:

```
valides :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

Should say this:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

If you look at the error message you can see that it is telling you that you are trying to call a method name valides, which does not exist.